# In rust convert a recursive algorithm to a loop

Tags: rust, heap-memory, borrow-checker

I have this code that scans a file and reports repetitions.

It is written in recursive style.

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::io::Read;
use std::fs::File;

fn read_strings(hm : HashSet<&str>, fd : &mut File) {
    let mut buf = [b'a'; 10];
    if fd.read_exact(&mut buf).is_err() {return};
    let mut hm = hm;
    let st = std::str::from_utf8(&buf).unwrap();
    if hm.contains(&st) {
        println!("duplicate {}", st);
    } else {
        hm.insert(&st);
    }
    read_strings(hm, fd)
}

fn main () {
    let mut fd = File::open("input.txt").unwrap();
    let hm = HashSet::new();
    read_strings(hm, &mut fd);
}
```

I want to write it as a loop.

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::io::Read;
use std::fs::File;

fn read_strings(hm : HashSet<&str>, fd : &mut File) {
    let mut buf = [b'a'; 10];
    let mut storage : Vec<String> = vec![];
    let mut hm = hm;
    while fd.read_exact(&mut buf).is_ok() {
        storage.push(String::from_utf8(buf.to_vec()).unwrap());
        let st = storage.last().unwrap().as_str();
        if hm.contains(&st) {
            println!("duplicate {}", st);
        } else {
            hm.insert(&st);
        }
    }
}

fn main () {
    let mut fd = File::open("input.txt").unwrap();
    let hm = HashSet::new();
    read_strings(hm, &mut fd);
}
```

It fails to compile giving this report.

```
$ rustc test.rs
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `storage` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> test.rs:10:9
   |
10 |         storage.push(String::from_utf8(buf.to_vec()).unwrap());
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
11 |         let st = storage.last().unwrap().as_str();
   |                  -------------- immutable borrow occurs here
12 |         if hm.contains(&st) {
   |            ---------------- immutable borrow later used here

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
```

I guess the crux of the problem is how to have a structure that you can at the same time allocate new elements and borrow existing ones.

The input.txt file contains just some caracters:

```
aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccaaaaaaaaaadddddddddd
```

The successful version when executed is giving this output:

```
$ ./test_rec
duplicate aaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: Since you don't return `storage` what's the point of populating it?

Comment: *"It fails to compile."* - please provide the output of `cargo check`. Stating that it fails to compile does not help. Further, please provide an example `input.txt` so we can reproduce it ourselves. Third, please show the expected output of your algorithm for the given `input.txt`. Otherwise it's really hard to help you, as we can't verify whether our answer contains errors.

Comment: @AlexeyS.Larionov this is not the whole aplication, the `storage` is holding the real data for multiple other structures to use references of it. In this cutout example the `storage` is holding the data in memory for `hm` so `hm` can just use references to the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is actually made of three parts.
They are left as is, because they illustrate different approaches which could be helpful for someone.
The first part deals with the problem as it was initially exposed in the question.
The second part tries to consider the further explanations provided as a comment (below) by the author of the question.
Finally, the third part considers a much more complicated situation (another comment below) in which we pretend the storage is not mutated, although it is, actually!

---

As stated in the comments, your `storage` variable seems useless since you don't return it.
I simply *guess* that you decided to use it because, while populating the hash-set with some string-slices (`&str`), the compiler was complaining about the fact that they referred to some `String`s that were disappearing immediately.
This was not the case in the recursive version because the local storage for the string-slice (`buf`) at each level of recursion still existed during the next level of recursion.
Moreover, the hash-set was consumed by each next recursion, thus it did not live longer than these storages.

In the following example, I simply consider that the hash-set **owns** the `String`s, which is much easier in terms of borrow-checking.
By the way, I decided to turn the hash-set parameter into an exclusive reference because I find it weird to create such an empty data structure at the call site but never have an opportunity to obtain its content.

Moreover, as suggested by @isaactfa, the `.contains()`/`.insert()` alternative can be simplified with `.replace()` (or testing the result of `.insert()` if the `println!()` is not needed afterwards).

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

fn read_strings(
    hm: &mut HashSet<String>,
    fd: &mut File,
) -> usize {
    let mut duplicate_count = 0;
    let mut buf = [b'a'; 10];
    while fd.read_exact(&mut buf).is_ok() {
        let st = String::from_utf8(buf.to_vec()).unwrap();
        if let Some(previous) = hm.replace(st) {
            println!("duplicate {:?}", previous);
            duplicate_count += 1;
        }
        /*
        if hm.contains(&st) {
            println!("duplicate {:?}", st);
            duplicate_count += 1;
        } else {
            hm.insert(st);
        }
        */
    }
    duplicate_count
}

fn main() {
    let mut fd = File::open("input.txt").unwrap();
    let mut hm = HashSet::new();
    let duplicate_count = read_strings(&mut hm, &mut fd);
    println!("{} duplicate(s)", duplicate_count);
    println!("{:?}", hm);
}
/*
duplicate "abcdefghij"
duplicate "klmnopqrst"
2 duplicate(s)
{"mnopqrstuv", "ijklmnopqr", "xyz\nabcdef", "uvwxyz\nabc", "yz\nabcdefg", "rstuvwxyz\n", "nopqrstuvw", "defghijklm", "abcdefghij", "pqrstuvwxy", "ghijklmnop", "klmnopqrst", "\nabcdefghi", "wxyz\nabcde", "opqrstuvwx", "tuvwxyz\nab", "jklmnopqrs", "fghijklmno", "vwxyz\nabcd", "efghijklmn", "hijklmnopq", "bcdefghijk", "z\nabcdefgh", "lmnopqrstu", "cdefghijkl", "stuvwxyz\na", "qrstuvwxyz"}
*/
```

---

This second version considers the OP's comments.
The main point was actually to keep the storage distinct from the hash-set referring to it.

For this solution to work, we need to explicitly handle the lifetimes (note the `'a` in `read_strings()`) in order to tell the compiler that the storage (the bytes from the file) must remain valid as long as the hash-set refers to it.

Instead of duplicating some sequences of 10 bytes, we iterate by chunks of this specific size and leave them in place.
The failure to consider these bytes as a valid utf-8 sequence is silently ignored instead of panicking; of course, you could handle that differently.

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn read_strings<'a>(
    whole_content: &'a [u8],
    hm: &mut HashSet<&'a str>,
) -> usize {
    let mut duplicate_count = 0;
    for chunck in whole_content.chunks_exact(10) {
        if let Ok(st) = std::str::from_utf8(chunck) {
            if !hm.insert(st) {
                println!("duplicate {:?}", st);
                duplicate_count += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    duplicate_count
}

fn main() {
    if let Ok(whole_content) = std::fs::read("input.txt") {
        let mut hm = HashSet::new();
        let duplicate_count = read_strings(whole_content.as_slice(), &mut hm);
        println!("{} duplicate(s)", duplicate_count);
        println!("{:?}", hm);
    }
}
/*
duplicate "aaaaaaaaaa"
1 duplicate(s)
{"dddddddddd", "bbbbbbbbbb", "aaaaaaaaaa", "cccccccccc"}
*/
```

---

This third version considers another comment about the original problem.
The input cannot be stored as a whole in memory, but should be read by small chunks.
The consequence is that the storage is supposed to grow while the hash-set still refers to its content; this does not sound very Rust-ish...

One possible solution is to rely on some unsafe code.
**As far as small-string-optimisation is not involved**, mutating a vector of `String`s by pushing some new elements, does not actually mutate or move the storage for the text these strings contain.
Then we can encapsulate this vector of strings in order to prevent from allowing any other operation than pushing, and discretely obtain the pointer to each string-slice.

As in the previous solution, the string-slices held by the hash-set must consider that the storage for the strings outlives them, hence the `'a` annotation.
And because many references will relate to this storage, it must be accessed through a shared reference (`&`, not `&mut`); this implies the use of *interior-mutability* (thanks to `RefCell`).

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

mod my_module {
    use std::cell::RefCell;

    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct Storage(RefCell<Vec<String>>);
    impl Storage {
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            Self(RefCell::new(Vec::new()))
        }
        pub fn store<'a>(
            &'a self,
            txt: &str,
        ) -> &'a str {
            self.0.borrow_mut().push(txt.to_owned());
            let ugly_ptr = self.0.borrow().last().unwrap().as_str().as_ptr();
            unsafe {
                let sl = std::slice::from_raw_parts(ugly_ptr, txt.len());
                std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(sl)
            }
        }
    }
}

fn read_strings<'a>(
    storage: &'a my_module::Storage,
    hm: &mut HashSet<&'a str>,
    fd: &mut File,
) -> usize {
    let mut duplicate_count = 0;
    let mut buf = [b'a'; 10];
    while fd.read_exact(&mut buf).is_ok() {
        if let Ok(st) = std::str::from_utf8(&buf) {
            if hm.contains(st) {
                println!("duplicate {:?}", st);
                duplicate_count += 1;
            } else {
                hm.insert(storage.store(st));
            }
        }
    }
    duplicate_count
}

fn main() {
    let mut fd = File::open("input.txt").unwrap();
    let storage = my_module::Storage::new();
    let mut hm = HashSet::new();
    let duplicate_count = read_strings(&storage, &mut hm, &mut fd);
    println!("{} duplicate(s)", duplicate_count);
    println!("hm: {:?}", hm);
    println!("storage: {:?}", storage);
}
/*
duplicate "aaaaaaaaaa"
1 duplicate(s)
hm: {"dddddddddd", "bbbbbbbbbb", "cccccccccc", "aaaaaaaaaa"}
storage: Storage(RefCell { value: ["aaaaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbbbb", "cccccccccc", "dddddddddd"] })
*/
```

Comment: Small note: `HashSet::insert` already returns a `bool` indicating whether the insertion is a duplicate, so the `hm.contains(...)` check is unnecessary.

Comment: @isaactfa very good suggestion, thanks. But I have a problem with the following `println!()` because `st` will have been consumed, even if not inserted. Well, I guess we could simply get rid of this `println!()`, but I wanted to stay as close as possible to the original example.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't considered that. If the print statement was crucial, you could use the [`replace` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.replace) which would return the duplicate back to you (if there was one) which you can then print out.

Comment: @prog-fh You are missing the point. The point is that I have multiple structures that are dealing with the same set of strings. For memory optimization reasons I use only one copy of them and use references all over. The example is a cutout of a bigger application. That `println!()` can be anything, it could "lunch nuclear warheads", so it is important. That storage is important because in the real big application is populated from different sources and is providing those references to different structures.

Comment: @E.Timotei OK then, you could probably adjust your question accordingly to this remark, because, in its current state, the variables `hm` and `storage` are not usable outside the `read_strings()` function. It's very difficult to imagine the real context of this problem. And what you explain here does not match with the recursive version which is supposed to work as you expect.

Comment: @prog-fh probably the question can be expressed better, I have put two solutions of the same problem the recursive one is doing the real data allocation on the stack and that is why you cannot get the `hm` back outside again, `hm` holds only references, this is the working one. The not working one is using a data structure for holding data and must do two things at the same time, allow references to the existing data, add new data. Using a vector will trigger the borrow checker. What could I add to the question to make this clearer?

Comment: @E.Timotei Well, I tried to do better this time ;^)

Comment: @prog-fh This is almost perfect. But in your solution you segregate the read from the processing. This is unfortunate. You can consider that the input.txt is a named pipe and not all data is available at the start. The application has to give incremental results when the duplicate appears. This is the hard problem, you do not have all the data available at the start, so you have to mutate the storage to add new data while you already have borrowed references to the old data in the storage. Can such a data structure exist?

Comment: @E.Timotei Ahahah, I just tried something else.

Comment: @prog-fh It is a shame that you have to steal the reference with unsafe code, but it is what it is.